# Normalize data and insert into table

Tags: sql, database-design

I have three table and their data. I have also desire output but i don't no how to normalize it.
Desire output:

```
    name   | title |    role    
----------+-------+------------
 Dilan    | si106 | Instructor
 Boshra   | si106 | Learner
 Kearney  | si106 | Learner
 Norea    | si106 | Learner
 Schuyler | si106 | Learner
 Sylvia   | si110 | Instructor
 Arzoo    | si110 | Learner
 Callin   | si110 | Learner
 Raja     | si110 | Learner
 Silas    | si110 | Learner
 Isher    | si206 | Instructor
 Arryn    | si206 | Learner
 Jemmia   | si206 | Learner
 Luciano  | si206 | Learner
 Pasquale | si206 | Learner
(15 rows)
```

Query:

```
SELECT student.name, course.title, roster.role
    FROM student 
    JOIN roster ON student.id = roster.student_id
    JOIN course ON roster.course_id = course.id
    ORDER BY course.title, roster.role DESC, student.name;
```

But i got this output:

Problem is here: Due to DESC the role are not printing like desire output.

```
name   | title |    role    
----------+-------+------------
 Boshra   | si106 | Learner
 Kearney  | si106 | Learner
 Norea    | si106 | Learner
 Schuyler | si106 | Learner
 Dilan    | si106 | Instructor
 Arzoo    | si110 | Learner
 Callin   | si110 | Learner
 Raja     | si110 | Learner
 Silas    | si110 | Learner
 Sylvia   | si110 | Instructor
 Arryn    | si206 | Learner
 Jemmia   | si206 | Learner
 Luciano  | si206 | Learner
 Pasquale | si206 | Learner
 Isher    | si206 | Instructor
(15 rows)
```

How can i get above output by change insertion into tables and not changing query?
my three tables are given below:

```
=> SELECT * FROM STUDENT;
 id |   name   
----+----------
  1 | Dilan
  2 | Boshra
  3 | Kearney
  4 | Norea
  5 | Schuyler
  6 | Sylvia
  7 | Arzoo
  8 | Callin
  9 | Raja
 10 | Silas
 11 | Isher
 12 | Arryn
 13 | Jemmia
 14 | Luciano
 15 | Pasquale
(15 rows)

select * from course;
 id | title 
----+-------
  1 | si106
  2 | si106
  3 | si106
  4 | si106
  5 | si106
  6 | si110
  7 | si110
  8 | si110
  9 | si110
 10 | si110
 11 | si206
 12 | si206
 13 | si206
 14 | si206
 15 | si206
(15 rows)

select * from roster;                                                                                                             
 id | student_id | course_id |    role    
----+------------+-----------+------------
 16 |          1 |         1 | Instructor
 17 |          2 |         2 | Learner
 18 |          3 |         3 | Learner
 19 |          4 |         4 | Learner
 20 |          5 |         5 | Learner
 21 |          6 |         6 | Instructor
 22 |          7 |         7 | Learner
 23 |          8 |         8 | Learner
 24 |          9 |         9 | Learner
 25 |         10 |        10 | Learner
 26 |         11 |        11 | Instructor
 27 |         12 |        12 | Learner
 28 |         13 |        13 | Learner
 29 |         14 |        14 | Learner
 30 |         15 |        15 | Learner
(15 rows)
```

So any one help me to normalize there tables so that i get desire output.

Comment: "normalize" doesn't mean anything in particular. What do you mean by it, exactly, with a reference? Regardless of that, what exactly are you trying to output, as a function of input? PS [mre] PS [ask] [Help]

Comment: The order in which records are stored in a table (a) should not be relied upon to ensure any particular ordering of results and (b) is not determined by the order of insertion, it is determined by the clustering key. Long story short, you can't change the order of your results without changing the `ORDER BY` in your query. Why are you so averse to just removing `DESC` from the order by clause?

Comment: ..`, roster.role ASC` ?

Comment: My desire output is given on the top. Only the problem is I got "Boshra" on top but i want "Dilan" on top.

Comment: Sir i have no access to update the query. I can only change the data in tables or edit tables.

Comment: Someone must have access to this query surely? Ask them to update it? Failing that the only way you can possibly affect the order of the results without changing the order by is to change the data. You could change "Instructor" to "Teacher" then it will be sorted on top without having to change the query. This is a ridiculous solution, but quite frankly, it is a bit of a ridiculous problem.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i get above output by change insertion into tables and not changing query?

You cannot.  The query is explicitly stating the ordering of the result set.  That puts "Learners" before "Instructors" because of the `DESC` ordering.

The query you want would use the `ORDER BY` without `DESC`:

```
 ORDER BY course.title, roster.role, student.name;
```

I am not aware of a collation (which controls the ordering) where `'I' > 'L'`.

There is no way to change the data (in a sensible) way to make the query return the results you want.  I mean, it might be possible to prepend each `roster.role` with a an "invisible" character and use that the control the sorting.  That would be a total hack and not at all recommended.